# Problem installing my Android apps

Tags: android

I don't know what is happening with my apps. It never happened before.
I see errors like this:

> [2011-04-10 11:53:22 - Rocket Project] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
>
> [2011-04-10 11:53:22 - Rocket Project] Please check logcat output for more details.
>
> [2011-04-10 11:53:22 - Rocket Project] Launch canceled!

How can I resolve this?

Comment: **[2011-04-10 11:53:22 - Rocket Project] Please check logcat output for more details.**  ---- So, did you check `logcat` output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken, there are some "new line" characters in your Manifest. Example you declare new Activity:

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.AAWidget" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Ok, if so, try to make all these declarations in only 1 line:

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.AAWidget" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: there's no use. still problem. :(

Comment: aaaah.. found it. :D , really true. there's something wrong with activity element. actually I wrote it "Activities.statusActivity" which should be ".Activities.statusActivity" . just because of one point. (doh) thank you so much dude!!

Answer (score 0):

It will be great If you can post the logcat output here. anyhow a quick google search shows that the error appears shows when running apps built on older sdk on phones with newer version. Hope this helps. just try to rebuild the app on latest sdk.

Comment: as I said above. there's nothing on the logcat which indicating error.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "older sdk" , I've never upgrade my phone before.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the following logcat output, which pointed to the problem in the manifest:

```
Invalid taskAffinity name 1 in package com.eazyigz.RussiaMediaSearch: bad character '1'
```

Once I deleted that line, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

always write activity name prefix with **package name**

instead of :

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.AAWidget" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

write with package name :

```
<activity android:name="com.example.HelloWorld.Activities.AAWidget" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```