# Android apk file Installation error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem installing my Android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609894/problem-installing-my-android-apps)

Any body can tell me how can I solve this error.
**Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED**

It generates when I am trying to install apk file into emulator or mobile. 
Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate..
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609894/problem-installing-my-android-apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609894/problem-installing-my-android-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this,

http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/d7e87b5aaed14d54/0a384df6ea35f367?lnk=gst&q=Mark+Murphy